# download doesn't work inside dialog jsf2 primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink, download, primefaces

I have this problem 
when I put download link into a dialog box it doesn't work, but when I put it into panelgrid it works
is it a bug in primefaces or what ?
do you have any idea

Comment: any chance of nested forms in your dialog ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I just understand why doesn't work for me, when I put download link inside dialog it works but if it is inside ui:repeat it doesn't work : I just test this is :  do you have any idea to make working this component inside ui:repeat, thanks

Comment: I tested also h-datatable ,unfortunately, it doesn't work, did you ever encounter this problem ?

Comment: Duplicate of [convert Bytes\[\] to StreamedContent fro download jsf2.0 primefaces3.3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914085/convert-bytes-to-streamedcontent-fro-download-jsf2-0-primefaces3-3-1) Please don't repost the same problem over and over. Instead edit and improve your original question on the very same problem.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I made this only because I didn't find the result of the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:form>
        <p:panel header="Query">
            <.......some come is here ........
                        <p:commandButton value="Export CSV" icon="ui-icon-document"
                            process="@this" rendered="#{xxx.showTable}"
                            oncomplete="exportConfirmationDialogShow.show()"></p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:panelGrid>              
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
```

Dialog ;

```
<p:dialog header="Choose Delimiter Type" id="dialogCSV"
        widgetVar="exportConfirmationDialogShow" resizable="false">
        <h:form id="csvForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                <h:outputLabel value="Delimiter:" />
                <p:selectOneRadio id="delimiter" value="#{xxx.delimiterType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tab" itemValue="tab" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pipe" itemValue="|"  />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Comma" itemValue="," />                        
                </p:selectOneRadio>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="exportCsv" value="Export CSV"
                actionListener="#{xxx.export2CSV}" ajax="false"
                onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(hideStatus)">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{xxx.exportFile}"
                    contentDisposition="attachment" />
            </p:commandButton>

        </h:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showStatus() {
                exportConfirmationDialogShow.show();
            }

            function hideStatus() {
                exportConfirmationDialogShow.hide();
            }
        </script>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: We prefer it here at SO if you include in your answer a brief description of how this code works, and specifically how it answers the original question. That helps to make these answers a better resource of others.